# Import image based off what UIIMageView is equal to nil

Tags: swift, import, uiimageview, photo

I have my app setup to import a picture. If there isn't a picture in the first UIImageView puts the imported picture there. If the first UIImageView does have something in it put picture in the second UIImageView. Finally if the first and second UIImageView put the picture in the third

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        if picture.image == nil {
            picture.image = image
        } else if picture.image == image {
            picture2.image = image
        } else if picture2.image == image {

            picture3.image = image
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue/question? Try to replace `== image` to `== nil` in the second and third if statement.

Comment: The issue is it seems to just be canceling its self out currently. I tried switching those to == nil and thats gotten it closer. It lets you fill in 1 but skips 2 and goes right to three

Comment: ... Thank you that did work .. I had the second picture hidden so thats why it was skipping 2.. Thank you! If you switch your comment to an Answer happy to make it as solved!

Comment: @subdan Please add your comment as an answer and then notify Mike to accept it so this question has "closure" and is not shown as unanswered. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `== image` to `== nil` in the second and third if statement because every picture should have different images.